# Issues in Keras-Ocr Running in GCP VM Notebook

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-dl-platform

Im running Keras-OCR implementation from the following repository in the Notebook created in GCP VM

https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr

The call to prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize(images) kills the Kernel. The error about Kernel has died is thrown.

The GCP VM is :
Version: common-cu113.m87
Based on: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (GNU/Linux 4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 x86_64\n)

Can you suggest on how it that to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like there are some dependency libraries that are not working anymore with the project and causing issues with overall performance of the library. I think your best course of action is to either rise an [issue request](https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr/issues) to the project or just fix the compatibility issues manually within the existing library.

Comment: Have you try, running the small sample in the repo? ( remove 1 image as is not valid url anymore )

Comment: Thanks Betjens. The issue is solved. It was issue with opencv-python version. For me it worked downgraded version of opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with opencv version. I had latest version which is 5.5.5. It worked when downgraded the version to 4.4